# How to send commits from developers to test environment, automatically

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit

I am the administrator of a project. And developers of my team, commit somethings by SVN. Normally, i am sending these commits to the test environment manually. Is it possible to send these commits to test environment, automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a continuous integration tool like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to do that.

It can be used to trigger a build at each change on the SVN. And then you can add a post-built script in charge of deploying (and eventually testing) the newly built application.

Answer (score 0):

A proper continuous integration tool like Jenkins is the right way to go forward.

> Is it possible to send these commits to test environment, automatically.

I assume the test server is Linux.

Then a cron job can be setup on test to run every say hour to svn export the project.

```
0 */1 * * * root auto_export_project.sh
```

Then in auto_export_project.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pushd /path/to/project
svn export http://repository_path/
popd
```